# Sonar alert : "private" methods that don't access instance data should be "static"

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar has this rule :

> `private` methods that don't access instance data should be `static`
>
> `private` methods that don't access instance data can be `static` to
>   prevent any misunderstanding about the contract of the method.

I have this alert in a method that create a new object from an anonymous inner class.

```
class Exemple {

 private Object _instanceObject;
    ...........
    private Something createSomething(String key) {
          return new Something(key) {
                @Override
                public Object getValue(Object element) {
                    return _instanceObject.getSomething(element);
                }
            };
    }
}
```

How `_instaceObject` is a non-static field. I  Can't make a static reference to the non-static field `_instanceObject`. As sonar says, I can not make this method static because there is an access instance data.

My problem is that Sonar doesn't see the use of `_instanceObject` inside the anonymous inner class so Sonar shows me the alert : **private" methods that don't access instance data should be "static"**. **Sonar says that I should make the method  `createSomething(String key)` static.**

> Make "createSomething" a "static" method.

Is  it appropriate to use the comment //NOSONAR to ignore this false violation indicated by Sonar ?

> [Ignore violations with the new ‘//NOSONAR’ comment](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-1-12-in-screenshots/)
>
> The NOSONAR tag tells Sonar to ignore all violations on a specific
>   line whatever rule engines are being used to scan code. Of course,
>   Sonar is still able to manage widely used //NOPMD and //CHECKSTYLE:OFF
>   … ON. We have simply added a native way to manage false positives.
>   This feature is a real improvement for users that have activated
>   Findbugs rules as there was no clean way to tag a Findbugs as a false
>   positive : there is now ‘//NOSONAR’.

Is it a known bug in sonar ?

Comment: Please post a complete example that generates the warning.

Comment: well, what is `instanceObject` and how is it declared

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Looks like an anti pattern.  Is the code thread safe ? There are far more issues with this code other than that very sonar warning.

Comment: Which method do you think is affected? `createSomething()` or `getValue()`? Think about it.

Comment: @Thomas the alert is on the method createSomething(), sonar suggest to me to make this method static. I updated the question with  this information

Comment: What version of the java plugin are you using?

Comment: @Massimo-SonarSourceTeam SonarQube™ technology is powered by SonarSource SA Version 5.1.2 - LGPL v3 - Community - Documentation - Get Support - Plugins - Web Service API

Comment: @Jesus SonarQube version (5.1.2) has nothing to do with the Java plugin version, if you provide your Java plugin version I can check if what you describe has already been fixed or get a reproducer.

Comment: @Massimo-SonarSourceTeam   SonarQube Java Analyser 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE, I get the alert in my eclipse and in the Sonar server that analyze the project.

Comment: @Jesus can you give it a try with Java plugin 3.6 to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Sonarqube is a helpful tool. But I would not investigate too much time in fixing issues that are obvious no issues. Just mark them as false-positive and go on to the next issue that might be a real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with the upgrade of Sonar to the version 5.1.2